# Python list comprehension: Flattening a list of lists returns a list of 5s

Tags: list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have the following list of lists:

```
>>>> vec=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

To flatten a list of lists using list comprehension I can use:

```
>>>>[i for k in vec for i in k]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

but if I write:

```
>>>> [i for k in vec]
[5,5,5]
>>>> [i for k in vec for k in k]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

or even change `vec=[[2,89,6],[34,7,10],[812,55,7],[76765,34,99]]`

```
>>>> [i for k in vec]
[5,5,5,5]
>>>> [i for k in vec for k in k]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

so what's happening? where do these 5s come from?

Comment: `i` has nothing to do with your list, since you're not using it as a loop variable any more. It still has the value `5` from some completely unrelated thing you did with it.

Comment: I don't know how you get this result, but [i for k in vec] gives an error: "i" is not defined...

Comment: Try `i` alone -- outside the list comprehension. Bet it is 5.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 3 as this question is tagged, then you must have rebound `i` to 5 at some point.  In Python 3 listcomps have their own scope, and so the commands you've shown won't even work:

```
>>> vec=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> [i for k in vec for i in k]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
>>> i
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
>>> [i for k in vec]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Because the listcomp doesn't set `i` to anything, it's trying to get a value from the outer scope, and (unlike you :-)  I haven't set it to anything.

By way of contrast, in Python 2, `i` would leak from the `[i for k in vec for i in k]` listcomp and you'd wind up with

```
>>> [i for k in vec]
[9, 9, 9]
>>> [i for k in vec for k in k]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```