# List Comprehension Returns List of Lists Instead of a Single List

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to use list comprehension to replace a `for` loop for the purpose of improving speed. Being new to list comprehensions, it appears that I do not have a complete grasp of how they work. My intent is to pass a list to a function that is held in memory to complete the processing that needs to be done, then return the list. In this simplified example, it looks like instead of returning the list I want it is returning a list of identical lists. So instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` I get `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`. I looked at the result [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182079/python-list-comprehension-flattening-a-list-of-lists-returns-a-list-of-5s) but it looks like they had a different problem.

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
k = []
def main():
    lst2 = [processfile(x) for x in lst1]
    print(lst2)
def processfile(i):
    k.append(i) 
    return(k)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a list then , you don't need to append the items in the lst1 to k just return i

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
def main():
    lst2 = [processfile(x) for x in lst1]
    print(lst2)
def processfile(i): 
    return(i)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In reality the problem is a 25 million row data frame is passed to the function which then needs to find matching values in one column and calculate values from the same rows in a different column, create 2 lists based on a given condition in another column, then return those two lists. This is a simplified example. I would like to understand the behavior.

Comment: If the function deals with a 25M row data frame, the performance of your code will _not_ improve by switching to a list comprehension.

Comment: @DYZ The question I am seeking an answer to is why does list comprehension generate a list of lists.

Comment: @Bar-Tzur if you want to deal more number of rows and need performance you should prefer numpy arrays instead of python lists, the list comprehension generates a list of lists because  the function `processfile(x)` returns a list by your initial code and that's the reason it generates list of lists

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @Tonystark. I'm curious why though?

Comment: @Bar-Tzur When the array size increases, Numpy gets around 30 times faster than Python List.Because the Numpy array is densely packed in memory due to its homogeneous type, it also frees the memory faster.So overall a task executed in Numpy is around 5 to 100 times faster than the standard python list, which is a significant leap in terms of speed. More than that  the numpy functions are implemented using C which is more faster than python obviously

Comment: @TonyStark that is really helpful. I'm going to look into how I can apply this to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just

```py
lst2 = [processfile(x) for x in lst1]
```

will be fine.

In that case you should do like below:

```py
def processfile(i): 
    return(i)
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to call the function in order to do other processing. Is there a way to coerce the function to return only a single list?

Comment: I would still need to execute the append so I would need a way to complete that and return the resulting value.

Answer (score 0):

Since `k` is only being used in the `process file()` function, avoid declaring it in the global scope. I didn't quite understand what you wanted/tried to do, but I hope this example will help you with list comprehension, also, I'd recommend you add 'Python' to the title of your post.

Here I will use list comprehension to add `1` to all items in `list1`.

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

def main():
    lst2 = [add1(item) for item in lst1]
    print(lst2)

def add1(num):
    return num + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Expected output is lst2 = `[2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: The post is tagged Python 3.x. With respect to your response, the global scope was a poor choice. In reality it is declared in main. The appending must occur in the actual code because that is where the list is being built from a data frame. I'm looking to understand what is happening to cause the generation of a list of lists.